# Google Spreadsheets formula to extract and convert currency from EUR/USD to Korean Won

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, format, currency

I am using two different columns, one for Korean Won and one for foreign currencies (USD and EUR). I am using the normal currency conversion for showing the foreign currencies.

I want the amount of the foreign currencies in row "R" to be shown in the "Q" row.

However, the formula below gives me just a zero.

```
=if(R2="[\$]\d+",GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDKRW"),
IF(R2="[\€]\d+",GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURKRW")))*R2
```

[**Korean Won in row Q and foreign currencies in row R:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R16o6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of this spreadsheet and look at sheets 2 and 3. They are two ways to accomplish what I think you want to do. Run sheet3 from the menu option 'Currency'. Let me know if you have any questions.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hiqq7AEgRENnUBVdCZPtQgfW1hybsgxJFPxi8IG5Z90/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, the result is that all amounts will be calculated to Korean Won using the EUR/KRW exchange rate. I cannot get the results for USD amounts.
Please note that I use the formats ($ #,##0.00) for showing the currencies. The currency symbols are not "really" existing.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data and expected results? I obviously don't understand your problem.

Comment: Please check the sheets i created for demonstration:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YyTyzGeEAgZmqLo-bpJxCSExRsG76-nM0Gh4-vcXD-M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ Michel Remiorsch See new answer.